# Set-Cookie header being ignored in iOS10

Tags: ajax, cookies, ios10

We are using Set-Cookie to achieve SSO for our application. It is working fine in android and iOS versions<10. But, for iOS10 though we are receiving Set-Cookie value in repsonseHeader , it is being ignored by safari. When I try jqHR.getAllResponseHeaders() method all the values except 'Set-Cookie' can be seen in console.

Can you please suggest a solution for this?